# @ks89/angular-modal-gallery remove image text from carousel description

Tags: javascript, angular, image-gallery

I am using this library for an angular image gallery.
[@ks89/angular-modal-gallery](https://ks89.github.io/angular-modal-gallery-2018-v7.github.io/gettingStarted)

I am using carousel mode with modalGaleryEnable for when the user clicks on an image the modal is displayed.

```
<ks-carousel [id]="111" [images]="imagesRect"
             [carouselImageConfig]="{description: {strategy: 2, imageText: ''}}"
             [carouselConfig]="{maxWidth: '766px', maxHeight: '400px', showArrows: true, objectFit: 'cover', keyboardEnable: true, modalGalleryEnable: true, legacyIE11Mode: false}"
             [previewConfig]="{visible: true, number: 5, width: 'auto', maxHeight: '100px'}">
</ks-carousel>
```

The text "Image X/X - Description" is displayed in the image description.

[image]

I need to delete the text "Image", I manage to do it for the carousel
using carouselImageConfig:

```
[carouselImageConfig]="{description: {strategy: 2, imageText: ''}}"
```

[image]

But for modal mode it doesn't work.
There is the configuration for modal mode:

```
<ks-modal-gallery [id]="0" [modalImages]="images"
    [currentImageConfig]="{description: {strategy: 2, imageText: ''}}"></ks-modal-gallery>
```

, but I don't know how to use it because I am not using modal gallery directly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of the library.
Yes, you are right, carouselImageConfig is an input parameter dedicated to carousels and not to the modal gallery.
At the moment you can't pass all inputs to modal gallery via carousel.

I fixed this with a new way to open modal gallery in the next major release (angular-modal-gallery v8.0.0) still in beta.

Comment: Stepano thanks for your answer. Can I install that beta using NPM?

Comment: Yes but don't use it in production. It's still very experimental without the official documentation and unit testing. It is still work in progress and I found a big issue with Angular 10 that I'm trying to fix.  Run npm i - g  @ks89/angular-modal-gallery@beta to install it.